# Telerik, export to pdf operation throwing an error, NotSupportedException: Font Century Gothic 9 Regular is not supported

Tags: pdf, fonts, telerik, containers

We are using telerik reporting for generating HTML as well as PDF reports. This time for container version, somehow while generating PDF report, telerik is throwing below error,

```
System.NotSupportedException: Font Century Gothic 9 Regular is not supported.
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.Fonts.TrueType.FontReader.GetFontData(Font font, Boolean& isTTC)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.Fonts.TrueType.TrueTypeDescriptor..ctor(Font gdiFont)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.PdfFontTable.GetDescriptor(PdfFont font)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.PdfFontDictionary..ctor(PdfDocument document, PdfFont drawingFont)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.PdfFontType0Dictionary..ctor(PdfDocument document, PdfFont font)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.PdfFontTable.GetFont(PdfFont font)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.PdfPageDictionary.GetFontName(PdfFont font, PdfFontDictionary& fontDictionary)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.Rendering.PdfRendererGraphicsState.Update(PdfFont font, Brush brush, Int32 renderMode)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.Rendering.PdfRenderer.Update(PdfFont pdfFont, Brush brush, Int32 renderMode)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.Rendering.PdfRenderer.DrawString(String text, PdfFont pdfFont, Brush brush, RectangleF rect, Boolean rightToLeft)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Pdf.Drawing.PdfGraphics.DrawString(String s, Font font, Brush brush, RectangleF rect, StringFormat format)
   at Telerik.Reporting.ImageRendering.CanvasPdf.DrawRegularChunk(String text, Font font, Brush brush, RectangleF rect, TextFormat textFormat)
   at Telerik.Reporting.ImageRendering.DocumentBase.WriteTextChunk(String text, RectangleF bounds, IFont font, Color foreground, TextFormat format)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Writing.HtmlTextWriter.WriteContent(DocumentWriter writer, HtmlTextElement element, ElementPageInfo pageInfo)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Writing.HtmlContentElementWriter`1.Write(T element, ElementPageInfo pageInfo, DocumentWriter writer)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Writing.WriteOperationsDispatcher.Visit(HtmlTextElement htmlTextElement)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ProcessingElementVisitor.Visit(LayoutElement element)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Writing.DocumentWriter.Telerik.Reporting.BaseRendering.IWriter.WriteStartElement(LayoutElement element, ElementPageInfo pageInfo)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Paging.PageElementLayer.AddToPage(IPageHandler handler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Paging.PageElementManager.AddToPage(IPageHandler handler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Paging.PageCompositionBase.SendPhysicalPages()
   at Telerik.Reporting.Paging.PageCompositionBase.OutputPage()
   at Telerik.Reporting.Paging.PageCompositionBase.CreatePages()
   at Telerik.Reporting.BaseRendering.RenderingExtensionBase.Render(Report report, Hashtable renderingContext, Hashtable deviceInfo, CreateStream createStreamCallback, EvaluateHeaderFooterExpressions evalHeaderFooterCallback)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.RenderCore(ExtensionInfo extensionInfo, IList`1 reports, Hashtable deviceInfo, IRenderingContext renderingContext, CreateStream createStreamCallback)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.ProcessAndRender(String format, ReportSource reportSource, Hashtable deviceInfo, IRenderingContext renderingContext, CreateStream createStreamCallback)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.ProcessAndRenderStateless(String format, ReportSource reportSource, Hashtable deviceInfo, IRenderingContext renderingContext, CreateStream createStreamCallback)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.RenderReport(String format, ReportSource reportSource, Hashtable deviceInfo)
```

Although I have **installed** century gothic font on a container and also proof that **HTML report working well**. Just PDF report throwing font error from telerik.

I looked into telerik blogs but do not understand why this would fail,
Links,
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-considerations-pdf
https://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-pdf-throwing-error

Interesting thing is, it works for on premise server but not for container so must be some installation or configuration expected by telerik's pdf report rendering. Please suggest some workarounds.

Comment: Are you sure that font is available and accessible to the process creating the PDF file? Looks like it throws when it tries to access the font data on disk.

Comment: Yes double sure that font is available as I confirmed by connecting to a container and also same font used by HTML report which works well.

Answer (score 0):

As much as the strange error is, the solution is more weird but works. As I explained in the question, getting this font not supported exception even though font is present under a container and after couple of search I only found one possible answer, that is to move font file somewhere else from "C:\Windows\Fonts" folder and then copy it back to the same folder. Eventually I tried this approach and it worked.

Followed this post, https://www.itwriting.com/blog/3050-font-does-not-support-style-regular.html

Somehow windows OS has its own way of producing an error and resolving the same :)